# How can I clear stdout of sub-process under ssh in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to clear stdout of a sub process under ssh.
Please see the following simplified code which does not have much meaning but it regenerates the phenomenon.

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import pickle

# *** I cannot modify the pre_defined_func() ***
print_func_py = 'def pre_defined_func():\n' \
            '    print("I want to clear this message but I could not.")\n' \
            '    return "answer" \n' \
            '\n' \
            'result = pre_defined_func() \n' \
            'import os \n' \
            'import pickle \n' \
            'import io \n' \
            'bytes = io.BytesIO() \n' \
            'byte_stream = pickle.dumps(result) \n' \
            'os.system(\'cls\' if os.name == \'nt\' else \'clear\') \n' \
            'print(byte_stream)'

print_func_py_sh = shlex.quote(print_func_py)

get_value_command = ['ssh', 'localhost', 'python3', '-c', print_func_py_sh]

get_value_process = subprocess.run(get_value_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print("stdout = {0}".format(get_value_process.stdout))
print("stderr = {0}".format(get_value_process.stderr))
```

The outputs are following,

```
stdout = b"I wat to clear this message but I could not.\nb'\\x80\\x03X\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00answerq\\x00.'\n"
stderr = b'TERM environment variable not set.\n'
```

I expected that "stdout = b'\x80\x03X\x06\x00\x00\x00answerq\x00.'"
which is a serialized data by pickle. However 'stdout' contains extra binary, 'I want to clear this message but I could not.\n'.

Before the line of 'print(byte_stream)', I tried to clear stdout by

```
'os.system(\'cls\' if os.name == \'nt\' else \'clear\') \n'
```

but it failed.

How can I clear stdout of sub process under ssh?

And what does message of stderr means?

Please tell me it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: hmmm... What are you trying to achieve at all? Why do you send your code as a string to remote machine and then try to run it? Are you sure there are no [better ways to do so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299657/run-local-python-script-on-remote-machine)?

Comment: Could somebody really understand why OP manually print some message which he claims that need to be removed?

Comment: @Sraw I guess OP simplified the real thing for us.

Comment: @Sraw ; it is simplified code as Alfe said.

Answer (score 1):

You have two things writing to stdout.  First the `pre_defined_func()` which gets called right away in your script, and then later the `print()` which dumps the pickle result.  The two outputs are just done one after the other, so, yes, what you receive is a concatenation of the two.  The `cls` or `clear` you attempted in between the two is just some more bytes which make a terminal clear its screen, but in a stream they are just some additional bytes.

Processes typically have two main output channels called stdout and stderr (output and error messages).  Default is to print to stdout, so often all the "results" are written there.  Any command doing output can decide to which of these channels the output shall go.  Btw, the message you see on the stderr just means that your `TERM` environment variable isn't set.  That typically shouldn't be a problem and is out of scope here.

I propose to separate the two things your script writes to the two channels stdout and stderr, then you can also separate them later in the reading script.  Just don't do the `clear` stuff, that doesn't help.  `ssh` luckily transports both channels separately, so this should also work.  Find my changes inline.  I also transformed your code to need way less quoting.

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import pickle

print_func_py = '''\
import sys

def pre_defined_func():
    print("I want to clear this message but I could not.",
          file=sys.stderr)
    return "answer"

result = pre_defined_func()
import os
import pickle
import io
bytes = io.BytesIO()
byte_stream = pickle.dumps(result)
print(byte_stream)
'''

print_func_py_sh = shlex.quote(print_func_py)

get_value_command = ['ssh', 'localhost', 'python3', '-c', print_func_py_sh]

get_value_process = subprocess.run(get_value_command,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print("stdout = {0}".format(get_value_process.stdout))
print("stderr = {0}".format(get_value_process.stderr))
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me the mechanism and a solution. But unfortunately, I cannot modify pre_defined_func(). I am sorry I did not mention it.

Comment: No problem, I was just assuming this might be an error message and under your control.  Then I propose to write the pickle data into a real file and do a second `ssh` call the collect it.  If you want to do it in one `ssh` call and both stdout and stderr are already contaminated with output you cannot suppress, then the only remaining option I see is to _search_ for the beginning of the pickle data.  That might be rather complex, though.  A marker might help.

Comment: thank you for the next solution. I will try your solution.